# Postgres select function in Django annotation

Tags: django, annotations

I have old database and need custom select.

in sql i can use:

```
SELECT x(geometry) FROM table
```

but I dont know how to force x() function in django select.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a custom function using [Expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/expressions/).

```
class GeoX(Func):
    function = 'X'

MyModel.objects.annotate(x=GeoX('field'))
```

This will result in the geometry X function being invoked and it's result being annotated to a field labeled x in your model. However this is the inferior solution. The better solution is to install geodjango. That provides full access to almost every single function in PostGIS. Also works with spatialite and msyql spatial extensions.

Comment: Thank you, unluckily my postgres version is to old for geodjango.

Comment: that's bad luck. Why not upgrade you are probably using an old version of postgis as well and that doesn't have the rich functionality of the modern version.

Comment: huge company, a lot of data and everyone afraid of upgrade xD

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve problem using Func()

```
Func(F('geometry'), function='x')
```